# What is the correct usage of "this" in Android Studio - ActivityCompat.requestPermissions?

Tags: android, android-studio-2.0

In using the method below, Android Studio is generating the following error on the keyword "this":

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_FINE_LOCATION);
```

Error:

> Wrong first argument type...found com.websmithing.wp.gpstracker.LocationService, required android.app. Activity

I can reference the activity using "this" without any error when evaluating the manifest file permissions check as per below.

```
ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)   !=
  PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) !=
  PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

`this` refers to the present class. It only works with `this` when you are in an activity while requesting permission.

**Solution**

Send a notification from the service so when the user clicks it, open the
activity and ask for the permissions you need.

**How do I send a notification?**

Simple refer to *[Building a Notification](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html)*.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to the error message. It's pointing you toward the solution.

> Wrong first argument type...found
>   com.websmithing.wp.gpstracker.LocationService, required android.app.
>   Activity

It means that `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()` is expecting an Activity as the first argument but you are providing a LocationService instance. I guess you are invoking this from an inner class, then perhaps you have to use `WhateverYouActivityClassIs.this` to refer to the outer class.

Comment: Yes, I am invoking from an inner class. Guess I just don't understand why the reference "this" works for the checkSelfPermissions as a valid activty but not for the request code... All the examples I have researched online use "this" as a valid form....

Comment: I believe my issue is that the inner class from which I am calling request permissions extends the Service class and is not an activity. Therefore the reference mainActivity.this will not work either.

Answer (score -1):

You have to write the `checkSelfpermission` code in the activity where you call the class.

Comment: Could you explain your answer and give us an example?

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.